# android - How we place the image in circle in canvas

Tags: android

I have this circle

```
canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2 , 20, paint);
```

How to set Image in this Circle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just simply draw a bitmap as a circle. You'll have to set an appropriate clipping region and then draw the bitmap.

To set your circle as clipping region use the following:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getWidth() / 2)+200, 20, Direction.CW);
canvas.clipPath(path);
```

Afterwards you can draw a bitmap in the center of this region e.g. like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getWidth() / 2) + 200 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, null);
```